# Post data and load form fields using Ajax and Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I have an appointment form for patients....appointment form contain fields for patient mr number,name,phone,date,time etc.....what i want is when user enter mr number inthe mr field the form should load the other fields with data of that patient if it is available in database...I am unable to call ajax and load data in form.....Please help

**Appointment Form:**

[image]

**Ajax Call:**

```
 $('#mr_number').on('keyup',function(){

          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: '/',
              data: {'mr_number':$('input[name=mr_number]').val()},
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function (data) 
              {
                console.log(data);  
              }
          });
    });
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/','AppointmentsController@searchpatient')->name('patient.search');
```

**Search Patient Function which will return the data for form fields:**

```
 public function searchpatient(Patient $mr_number)
    {
        return ($mr_number);

    }
```

Comment: Well, just at a quick glance you're ajax call is doing `dataType: 'JSON'` which says the response **must** be json.  But you're searchpatient method is just returning the $mr_number object.  Does your router know to turn that into json?

Comment: i didn't write that code to turn into JSON for router....i am new to ajax so don't know much about how can i call or post data through ajax...

Answer (score 0):

First this is first assign the mr_number outside of the ajax call

```
var mr_number = $('input[name=mr_number]').val();
```

The lravel ajax call need to have th _token for CSRF blocking

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/',
    data: {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}',
            mr_number:mr_number},
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        failure: function(data){
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

//inside of your controller

```
public function searchpatient(Request $request){
    return response()->json($request->input('mr_number'));
}
```